# Can't create new Prism project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, prism

I can't create a new Prism (Xamarim.Forms) project anymore 'cause I'm getting this error

```
    Requested value 'autofac' was not found
```

from visual studio when I try to create the project.
I've tried with both visual studio 2017 and 2019, 'till few days ago I had no problems creating Prism projects and I have no idea of what changed.

Comment: Here is a official document. https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Getting-Started.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved removing this key "SelectedContainer" in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Prism

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if the autofac library is present inside nuget packages?

Else an alternative is does the download from nugetpackages 
Install-Package Prism.Autofac.Forms -Version 7.1.0.431

or 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Autofac.Forms/

Comment: I can't add autofac manually 'cause it doesn't create the project at all. I do New -> Project then select "Prism Blank App (Xamarin.Forms) and when i click on OK I get the error

Comment: I had this problem in visual studio 2019 by the way i needed to create a new project in windows does a push and clone in  mac os